# NHibernate One to One Foreign Key ON DELETE CASCADE

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I need to implement One-to-one association between Project and ProjecSettings using fluent NHibernate:

```
public class ProjectMap : ClassMap<Project>
{
   public ProjectMap()
   {
      Id(x => x.Id)
        .UniqueKey(MapUtils.Col<Project>(x => x.Id))
        .GeneratedBy.HiLo("NHHiLoIdentity", "NextHiValue", "1000",
           string.Format("[EntityName] = '[{0}]'", MapUtils.Table<Project>()))
        .Not.Nullable();

      HasOne(x => x.ProjectSettings)
        .PropertyRef(x => x.Project);
    }
}

public class ProjectSettingsMap : ClassMap<ProjectSettings>
{

    public ProjectSettingsMap()
    {

      Id(x => x.Id)
        .UniqueKey(MapUtils.Col<ProjectSettings>(x => x.Id))
        .GeneratedBy.HiLo("NHHiLoIdentity", "NextHiValue", "1000",
          string.Format("[EntityName] = '[{0}]'", MapUtils.Table<ProjectSettings>()));

      References(x => x.Project)
        .Column(MapUtils.Ref<ProjectSettings, Project>(p => p.Project, p => p.Id))
        .Unique()
        .Not.Nullable();
    }
}
```

This results in the following sql for Project Settings:

```
CREATE TABLE ProjectSettings (
  Id                       bigint PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  Project_Project_Id       bigint NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  /* Foreign keys */
  FOREIGN KEY (Project_Project_Id)
    REFERENCES Project()
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
```

What I am trying to achieve is to have ON DELETE CASCADE for the FOREIGN KEY (Project_Project_Id), so that when the project is deleted through sql query, it's settings are deleted too. How can I achieve this ?

**EDIT**: I know about Cascade.Delete() option, but it's not what I need. Is there any way to intercept the FK statement generation?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Fluent-NHibernate can't do this.

You can do this :

```
HasOne(x => x.ProjectSettings).PropertyRef(x => x.Project).Cascade.Delete();
```

This will work as intended, but the DDL won't change, FNH will handle the cascade programmatically rather than using the DB engine.

Comment: I know about Cascade.Delete(), but it's not what I need. Is there any way to intercept the FK statement generation?

Comment: Not with FNH, no. You can try to use NHibernate.Mapping.IAuxiliaryDatabaseObject in NHibernate config, which might be able to do this, but as far as I know, FNH has no answer to this.

Comment: Well, thanks for pointing the direction. Though I hoped there is an easier way.